# Extract Zip File from remote server with white-space in file name

Tags: php

I have a list of zip files to read from a remote server. The list of the files are as follows:

```
  CA-EN Bosch 20170901.zip
  CA-EN Gaggenau 20170901.zip
  CA-EN Thermador 20170901.zip
```

As we can see here, all filenames are with white-space in it. Due to this My code is unable to extract these zip files.
Following is what I am using to extract file contents:

```
    $destination = '../../boschzip'; 

    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $res = $zip->open('CA-EN Bosch 20170901.zip'); // Your filename
    if ($res === TRUE) {
        $zip->extractTo('../../boschzip');
        $zip->close();die;
    }
    else{
        echo 'Error Message. :(';die;
    }
```

I can not make any change in the file name as it is on the client's server. So is it possible to extract these zip files with white-space in their file names.

Comment: Have you tried escaping the space? '\ '

Comment: @SmileIT No I have not. Could you please tell me, how can we do it...

Comment: That can never be the complete path to the ZIP file if it is not on the same computer as the script. So it will simply not open because it doesn't exist. Check the value that is returned from `open()` it will tell you the type of error.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, Do you mean to say that, it is not possible with file name having white-space in it.. I have tried manually  removing the space and is working fine. But what about the file-name with space?

Comment: Whitespace is not the issue I just tried a similar scenario on my system, and it worked fine. Make sure your code is able to access the file. Whether it even exists or not.

Comment: use file_get_contents to fetch from remote then file_put_contents to write locally and then use your Zip code to process it.

Comment: @mega6382, I am sure about the file that it exists on the remote server. As at the same directory I have tested with other file with no space in its name. and that is working fine.

Comment: You said you had no write access to the client's server. This is making less and less sense.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I think OP meant, that he can make changes but is not allowed to.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, Sorry If it sounded like that but it is not correct. I am not allowed to make any change on client's files on his server.

Comment: Please help me out of it. I really am stuck due to this silly white space thing. I really have no Idea, why is it creating issue with space in file name. If it is possible, please tell me how and if not then could you please give me a reason which I can explain further.